# Custom BottomNavigationBar widget does not change icon color to green when I tap on other BottomNavigationBarItem

Tags: flutter

Custom flutter BottomNavigationBar widget does not change icon color to green when I tap on other BottomNavigationBarItem.

I have added the setState() function to update the `_selectedIndex` and set `selectedItemColor`. Also, all the pages inside the app are using global `globalNavBar`, to eliminated multiple renders.

But no matter which item I tap. only "Home" is showing green color, other icons remain unchanged.

So I wonder the following error: User tap on the nav item, and it jumps to a new page. The page rendering starts, but it was unable to detect the nav item tap action because the nav item tap action was recorded in the previous page. If so, how can I fix it?

**elements/nav.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../global_var/page.dart';

class MyNavBar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _MyNavBarState();
  }
}

class _MyNavBarState extends State<MyNavBar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int _selectedIndex = 0;

    return BottomNavigationBar(
      items: [
        // https://material.io/resources/icons/?style=baseline
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.home, size: 30),
          title: new Text(
            'Home',
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal, fontSize: 13),
          ),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.local_dining, size: 30),
          // local_dining, restaurant
          title: new Text(
            'Order',
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal, fontSize: 13),
          ),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.redeem, size: 30),
          title: Text(
            'Rewards',
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal, fontSize: 13),
          ),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.store_mall_directory, size: 30),
          title: Text(
            'Locations',
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal, fontSize: 13),
          ),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.more_horiz, size: 30),
            title: Text(
              'More',
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal, fontSize: 13),
            ))
      ],
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
      selectedItemColor: Colors.green,
      onTap: (int index) {
        setState(() {
          _selectedIndex = index;
          print('_selectedIndex');
          print(_selectedIndex);
        });

        if (index == 0) {
          Navigator.push(
              context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => homePage));
        }
        if (index == 1) {
          Navigator.push(
              context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => orderPage));
        }
        if (index == 2) {
          Navigator.push(
              context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => rewardPage));
        }
        if (index == 3) {
          Navigator.push(
              context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => locationPage));
        }
        if (index == 4) {
          Navigator.push(
              context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => morePage));
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**global_var/page.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../locations_page.dart';
import '../order_page.dart';
import '../rewards_page.dart';
import '../more_page.dart';
import '../home_page.dart';

StatefulWidget homePage =  MyHomePage();
StatefulWidget orderPage =  OrderPage();
StatefulWidget rewardPage =  RewardPage();
StatefulWidget locationPage =  LocationPage();
StatefulWidget morePage =  MorePage();
```

**global_var/vars.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../elements/nav.dart';


StatefulWidget globalNavBar = MyNavBar();
```

**more_page.dart**

```
class MorePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MorePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MorePageState createState() => _MorePageState();
}

class _MorePageState extends State<MorePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    AppBar appBar = Bar().getAppBar(context);
        ...
        ...
        bottomNavigationBar: globalNavBar,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting "unselectedItemColor" as well?

Comment: I also think `int _selectedIndex = 0;` should not be inside of the `build` method. Every time you call `setState()` - `build` fires again.